# Speed Test: Setting Domain In Matches Or Checking With Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm injecting a script with matches property in content_scripts of manifest.json in chrome extension. Would it be better if I add all the list of matching domains to manifest.json or checking them in the javascript included?

Thanks!

My manifest.json:

```
....
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
....
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the length of your list.

Comment: Say its 100. Then? Check with javascript or check with matches?

Comment: It also depends on if you plan on adding new ones frequently. If so you'll want to do it in the JS so every update doesn't require new permissions.